# Why does this scope-based timer not work as intended?

Tags: timers, stm32

I wrote the following scope-based timer to help me profile my code and improve its efficency, but in testing I found that it reports durations far shorter than it should:

```cpp
class CodeTimer {
 public:
  CodeTimer(const String& name) : _name(name) {
    Serial.println("Begin execution of \"" + _name + "\".");
    _begin = micros();
  }

  ~CodeTimer() {
    unsigned long duration = micros() - _begin;
    Serial.println("\"" + _name + "\" execution took " + duration + "µs.");
  }

 private:
  unsigned long _begin;
  String _name;
};
```

For example, I'd use it like so in my sketch:

```cpp
void setup() {}

void loop() {
  CodeTimer("void loop()");
  int begin = millis();

  delay(100); // Simulation of work that takes 100ms.
  Serial.println(millis() - begin);
}
```

Then, when I go to run the above sketch on my Blue Pill board (*STM32F103C8*), I get something like this printed to the terminal:

```
Begin execution of "void loop()".
"void loop()" execution took 4µs.
100
Begin execution of "void loop()".
"void loop()" execution took 3µs.
101
Begin execution of "void loop()".
"void loop()" execution took 4µs.
100
```

Something is very wrong with when the destructor to `CodeTimer` is being called, and I'm not exactly sure what it is.

Comment: the code is optimized by the compiler. It executes the prints and ready. there is no reason to hold the object on stack longer

Comment: @Juraj Interesting... Is there any way I can prevent it from doing this?

Comment: Access the instance after the delay.

Comment: @Juraj This makes sense, thank you. However, I'd still be interested in knowing if there's some sort of compiler flag or keyword I can use to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Sure, but I mean like for just this one class/instance.

Comment: Maybe if you make `_begin` a static member...? Untested, just off my head

Comment: :-) the coders on Stack Overflow have better eyes (or experience). the variable name is missing so there is no variable to live until the end of the scope https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496359/prevent-compiler-from-calling-class-deconstructor-before-scope-completed

Comment: Yes, I discovered this earlier today. Kicking myself for not seeing this...